# Wifi not working in Ubuntu 16.04 after chown on /var/ directory

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I executed `sudo chown -R mahesh:mahesh .` in `/var/www/html` directory without realising the full consequences. Now my wifi is not being detected at all. However, ethernet is up and running.

[The dump of the wireless-info script is here](https://pastebin.com/c1htLcQq)

Please suggest actions to get wifi working.

Comment: @Mahesh please [edit] your question and show us the exact command you ran.

Comment: You seem to have an "alias interface" `wlp7s0:avahi` - try `sudo ifdown wlp7s0:avahi`, `sudo ifdown wlp7s0` and `sudo ifup wlp7s0`.

Comment: The contents of your/var/www/html/ folder should be owned by www-data:www-data. The /var/www/ folder itself is owned by root on my system iirc